# OnNavigatedTo in MVVM pattern for Windows Store Apps

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, mvvm-light

How can I implement the `OnNavigatedTo` and `OnNavigatedFrom` methods in a Windows Store App with MVVM pattern? I'm currently using MVVM Light and the closest thing I found to my solution is this: [link](https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/05/07/calling-viewmodel-methods-in-response-to-page-navigation-events-using-mvvm-light-in-winrt/) 
However, it does not seem a very clean way to do it and it dates back to 2013, so I wonder if there is nicer way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with this way to solve it.

Prism, from Microsoft Pattern & Practices has a base Page class too which implements LayoutAwarePage (to get notified when the page layout/orientation changes). Having a base class which handles navigation events is fine.

Prism does it in the [FrameNavigationService](https://prismwindowsruntime.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#8.1/Prism.StoreApps/FrameNavigationService.cs), which is ultimately tied to the Frames "Navigated" event handler [FrameFacadeAdapter](https://prismwindowsruntime.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#8.1/Prism.StoreApps/FrameFacadeAdapter.cs)

**Edit:**
Of course instead of editing the XAML file to use the you can also derive from it if I remember correctly (can't validate at work, but in your code behind you should be able to change `public class MyPage : Page` into `public class MyPage : BindablePage`.